# chage the value of a variable using a const type * by the way of construct, isn't it illegal？

Tags: c++

code here：

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int a=15;
    const int*ap=&a;
    allocator<iterator_traits<decltype(ap)>::value_type>aallo;
    cout<<"before construct:"<<a<<endl;   //15
    aallo.construct(ap,27);               //isn't illegal?
    cout<<"after construct:"<<a<<endl;    //27
}
```

here ,we can change the value of a from its pointer  ap,but the ap is a const int*,it must not be modified by ap.but here it works using allocator.construct,isn't it illegal？ 
fresh man asking,thank you!

Comment: You've found a really complicated way to say `*const_cast<int*>(ap)=27;` which is perfectly valid as `a` isn't `const`. If `a` was `const` then both of these would be UB.

Comment: yeah，my code just remove the const feature like the const_cast .Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

it is legal since internally `construct` use `placement-new`.

So what happens is:
`new((void *)ap) int(27);` and since the memory pointed by `ap` is allocated and not `const`, placement-new works just fine.

It's the same as doing `new((void *)&a) int(27);`

---

That said, let's make `a` `const`: `const int a=15` 
Now the following code will compile too

```
 const int a=15;
 int *aa = (int*)&a;
 *aa=27;
```

because that cast will get rid of the type safety and force the conversion. It' UB obviously. The same way the cast in the `placement-new` will compile and be UB.

It's your responsibility to make sure you don't use `const` memory in placement-new expressions.

Answer (score 0):

No.

It is only illegal to modify a `const` object. Since `a` is not a `const` object, it is perfectly legal, and well-defined, to modify its value.

But the code could crash if you change the code to:

```
const int a=15;
```

Comment: But it would still compile if you changed to `const int`, won't it? The use of `value_type` discards the `const`.

Comment: Yes, but then the code would not have well-defined behavior because it is illegal to modify a `const` object. It might be stored in memory that is not writable, for example. Or multiple `const` objects with the same value might be stored in the same place!

Comment: Yes, it will compile with `const int` as shown [here](https://godbolt.org/g/gQcCXp). It will fail if they will try passsing const object to the `iterator_traits`

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I think that's the point of the question. Why does this enable violating const-correctness?

Comment: @Barmar,Yes,the point I want to talk  is why this can   enable violating const-correctness .And it is just like the const_cast ,remove the const feature.

Comment: @zhangshaui Because `value_type` doesn't include the `const` attribute. `const` is an attribute of a location, not a value.